# How to set Assigned To Id in task to Account.OwnerId in task after insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following code

```
trigger AssignTaskOwner on Task (after insert) {
Task myTask=trigger.new[0];
Task updacc=[select id from task where id = :myTask.id];
updacc.OwnerId= 'somestring';
update updacc;
}
```

updacc. doesn't give us the option Account.OwnerId but if I do a select Account.OwnerId from task, I get an Id. 
How do I pass that in for updacc.OwnerId instead of string? If I do

```
    Id accountOwner = [select Account.OwnerId from task where id = :myTask.id Limit 1];
```

and try to pass that in instead I get an Illegal assignment from List to Id. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing Your Syntax

You need to pull the Id from your record. To make your attempt work, you would have to do:

```
Id accountOwner = [SELECT Account.OwnerId FROM Task WHERE Id = :myTask.Id].Account.OwnerId;
```

---

### Trigger Best Practice

However, this approach is not bulk safe. What you should really be doing is getting *all* of the values in one query, then retrieving them from a local map. **[Please note also that all field updates should go in a *before* context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)**:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Given the switch from `after insert` to `before insert`, you have to query the `Account` records, since the `Task` records won't yet be in the database. One other ramification of this change (and a big reason you should make it) is that you remove the `update` statement, so you no longer add DML Operations needlessly.

---

### Final Trigger

You can break this task down into a few common discrete steps.

1. Collect the related record Id values:

   ```
   Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
   for (Task record : newRecords)
   {
       accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
   }
   ```
2. Query and map the related records:

   ```
   Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([
       SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds
   ]);
   ```
3. Iterate and retrieve related record:

   ```
   for (Task record : trigger.new)
   {
       Account parent = accounts.get(record.AccountId);
       if (parent != null) record.OwnerId = parent.OwnerId;
   }
   ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96555/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-how-to-set-assigned-to-id-in-task-to-accou).